# Как включить темную тему в Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue3, vuetify

коллеги.

Использую в своем приложении на Vue3 готовую библиотеку Vuetify, смотрел в документации, как включить темную тему, повторил, не получается.

Может вы подскажете?

Код vuetify.js:

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'

// Vuetify
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify({
theme: {
  defaultTheme: dark
  }
})
```

Код компонента App.vue:

```
<script>
import SideBar from "@/components/SideBar.vue"
import Wallet from "@/pages/Wallet.vue";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar.vue";
import Registration from "@/pages/Registration.vue";
import MainLanding from "@/pages/MainLanding.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MainLanding,
    Registration,
    Navbar,
    SideBar,
    Wallet
  },
  data(){
    return {
      theme: useTheme(),
    }
  }
}
</script>


<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-theme-provider theme="dark">
<!--  Sidebar  -->
<!--    <SideBar v-if="isAuth"/>-->
    <Navbar/>
    <v-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </v-theme-provider>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

После изменения *vuetify.js* все должно работать.
Если вы задаете `defaultTheme: dark` глобально, так, как это сделали вы, то это уже применяется ко всем компонентам. Если же вы используете `<v-theme-provider theme="dark">` то темная тема примениться лишь вложенным в нее компонентам.

Вот пример моего кода, тут глобальная тема светлая, а компонент card - темный.

Надеюсь это вам поможет, удачи !)

*vuetify.ts* (в вашем случае js)

```
export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'light',
  },
})
```

*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-theme-provider theme="dark">
        <v-card
        text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit.." />
      </v-theme-provider>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Спасибо за помощь